# Spring - Inject bean using Autowire

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations, javabeans

I'm trying to inject a bean in a simple java project but I'm getting a NullPointerException for ProductInformationServiceImpl.

These are the classes I'm using:

AppConfig.java (Spring configuration class)

```
package com.test.testing.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test")
public class AppConfig {
}
```

TestService.java interface:

```
package com.test.testing.service;

public interface TestService {
    String doIt();
}
```

TestService.java implementation:

```
package com.test.testing.service;

@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {
    public String doIt() {
        return "you did it!";
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
package com.test.testing;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        Test w = new Test();
        System.out.println(w.getTestService().doIt());
    }
}

class Test {
    @Autowired
    private TestService testServiceImpl;

    public TestService getTestService() {
        return testServiceImpl;
    }

    public void setTestService(TestService testServiceImpl) {
        this.testServiceImpl = testServiceImpl;
    }
}
```

I did some tests retrieving the bean using:

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
TestService app = (TestService)context.getBean("testServiceImpl");
```

But that is something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Autowired will work only if you get bean from context. You can use JUnit with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) and @ContextConfiguration for testing, it is a right way.

Comment: Try to use a Debugger to see which beans are in your `context`.

Comment: Sorry, it's not a @Test what I'm trying to achieve. This is a simple standalone application. Using ´´context´´ is what I'm trying to avoid, I'd just like to do the Autowiring..

Comment: You still need a context, without an `ApplicationContext` nothing will happen (just like now). You need a spring container.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the general suggestion id to use constructor injection instead of field injection, that helps you a lot with the testability.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@Autowired))
public class Animal {
    private final Sound sound;
    public String makeSound() {
        return sound.make();
    }
}
```

In the test you can pass the mocks or whatever in the constructor, while when you run your application the constructor injection will be taken care of automatically.
Here's a tiny [test app](https://github.com/csabakecskemeti/inject) which a showcase of the constructor injection.